# Add custom menu option in mouse right click event

Tags: vba, mouseevent, ms-word

When some words is selected in the document and right click, macro function should be called. Or something like, custom right click menu option should be added and when I click that menu option, macro should be called.

For example:

In the document I have four digit numbers like 2001 and 2010. When I select four digit number and hit right click and press my custom menu option, macro should be called and selected four digit no. should be parsed to the macro function which is called.

I got some code but its for Excel, I dont't know how to customize it for Microsoft Word.

Code for excel:

```
Const strMacro = "YourCode"

Sub CreateMacro()
   Dim cBut
   Call KillMacro
   Set cBut = Application.CommandBars("Cell").Controls.Add(Temporary:=True)
   With cBut
       .Caption = strMacro
       .Style = msoButtonCaption
       .OnAction = "Test_Macro"
   End With
End Sub

Sub Test_Macro()
   MsgBox "I work"
End Sub

Sub KillMacro()
   On Error Resume Next
   Application.CommandBars("Cell").Controls(strMacro).Delete
End Sub
```

Comment: What version of Word are you using? The method for doing this is varies depending on whether you're using Word with the ribbon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Microsoft Word 2007, I have pasted the macro code to add a custom menu option in the right click mouse event and getting the selected text into the function.

Macro:

```
Option Explicit
Sub CreateMacro()
    Dim MenuButton As CommandBarButton
    With CommandBars("Text")
        Set MenuButton = .Controls.Add(msoControlButton)
        With MenuButton
            .Caption = "Press Me"
            .Style = msoButtonCaption
            .OnAction = "Test_Macro"
        End With
    End With
End Sub

Sub Test_Macro()
    MsgBox Selection.text
End Sub

Sub ResetRightClick()
    Application.CommandBars("Text").Reset
End Sub
```